# Як назвати "дівоче" прізвище хлопця, що взяв прізвище дружини?

Tags: словосполучення

Звісно, практика, коли чоловік бере у шлюбі прізвище дружини, не така поширена в Україні, але все ж: чи є спеціальна назва для цього прізвища, тобто відповідник `дівочого прізвища` для чоловіків, крім зовсім вже офіційного "прізвище при народженні"?

Comment: Як щодо ***парубоче***? ;) [ПА́РУБОК](http://sum.in.ua/s/parubok), бка, чол.

Comment: Боюся здатися нудним, але у нас ще недостатньо розвинені мовні інструменти, повʼязані з емансипацією. Більшість подібних слів створюються прямо зараз, і ми можемо долучитися до цього створення. Щоправда, є варіанти виду *дошлюбне*, але воно, НМД, виглядає дещо сухим і офіційним.

Comment: парубоче прізвище, що пропонує @OksanaGubrenko, мені здається чудовим варіантом, дякую

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Проаналізувавши запропоновані варіанти: ***`прізвище при народженні`***, ***`дошлюбне прізвище`***, ***`парубоче прізвище`***, - дійшла таких висновків.

**`Прізвище при народженні`**. В деяких випадках може не відповідати запитуваному значенню, бо може бути синонімічним ***`прізвищу до зміни`*** (*після усиновлення, за власним бажанням* тощо, а не тільки *в результаті шлюбу*). Крім цього, не розрізняється за статтю.

**`Дошлюбне прізвище`**. Також  такий собі "унісекс". Окрім цього, може мати значення - ***`прізвище від попереднього шлюбу`***, якщо шлюб - не перший і щоразу зі зміною прізвища.

Утім, слід зазначити, що українське законодавство оперує терміном ***`дошлюбне прізвище`*** (для кожного з подружжя).

[Сімейний кодекс України](http://search.ligazakon.ua/l_doc2.nsf/link1/T022947.html)

> Стаття 35. Право на вибір прізвища при реєстрації шлюбу
>
> 1. Наречені мають право обрати прізвище одного з них як спільне прізвище подружжя або надалі іменуватися *дошлюбними прізвищами*.

**`Парубоче прізвище`**. Мій голос за цей варіант. Аргументи такі.

Як влучно зауважив [@bytebuster](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/users/8/bytebuster) у коментарі,

> у нас ще недостатньо розвинені мовні інструменти, повʼязані з
>   емансипацією.  Більшість подібних слів створюються прямо зараз, і ми
>   можемо долучитися до цього створення.

Логічно, що при виборі найбільш доречного прикметника слід орієнтуватися на значення іменника, від якого утворються прикметник. Я розглянула два: [парубок](http://sum.in.ua/s/parubok) і [юнак](http://sum.in.ua/s/junak).

***`Парубок`*** охоплює значення *нежонатий чоловік* і, в моєму розумінні, може вживатися для характеристики вже не юного, та все ще нежонатого легіня. Тому *парубоче*, а не *юнацьке*.

Додатковий плюс - розмежування за статтю, при цьому співзвучність, я б навіть сказала римованість: ***`дівоче/парубоче`***.